# BrowserMatch in Virtual Hosts files

Tags: virtualhost

We're busy migrating some websites to a new environment, so also transfer the Virtual Hosts files. I see these lines in the Virtual Hosts files:

```
  BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
  nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
  downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
  BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
```

Should I keep them or is this obsolete?

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://lists.debian.org/debian-apache/2016/02/msg00011.html, but still not sure.